# Is there a "Jetty server builder" project out there?

Tags: java, spring-mvc, jersey, jetty, embedded-jetty

Jetty is a great container for embedding in tests or standalone apps for various purposes, and part of the reason it's good at that is that it's easy to embed because it only takes a handful of lines of code. Some of us (me) aren't satisfied with that, though, and want a more concise solution. I'm looking for a library that acts as a builder for Jetty servers for various scenarios. For instance, I'd like to be able to say:

```
Server server = JettyServerBuilder.newSpringMvcServer()
    .withRootContext(rootContext).withDispatcherName("myapp")
    .atContextPath("/myContext");
```

to get a server that's set up for a typical Spring MVC app or

```
Server server = JettyServerBuilder.newJerseyServer()
    .withApplication(MyJaxRsApplication.class)
    .atContextPath("/myRestApi");
```

to get a server using Jersey to run my JAX-RS application.

Those are just a couple of possible examples, of course, and if there's a project out there that's similar but doesn't support exactly these technologies, I'm still interested to take a look at it. I'd even accept something that does this for something other than Jetty, as long as the support is there for setting up a wide variety of application types. Does anybody know of something like this?

Answer (score 2):

I have wanted to have one of these for quite some time, just not gotten around to it.  So, no there is no official one...would be nice to add to the project someday.

I always envisioned something like:

Server server = new FileServer().onPort("8080").onPath("/foo").withResourceBase("/path/here");

And just have a number of simple servers defined.

[edit] if you like open a bug for it at bugs.eclipse.org under RT/Jetty, it would be nice to make one of these for jetty 9